# How to Handle delays that made by multiple timeouts (containing ajax calls)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, performance

Consider I have multiple (sometimes more than 12) ajax calls that are calling every 2 seconds or more. Data gathered through the calls are set to the UI contained elements (Like progress bars). After all I have delay on **SCROLL** while timers working . This delay is natural, But How can I handle it?

**NOTE:** Calls Destinations are services that provides data with the minimum spent time. The point that makes the scroll sad, is using multiple `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` methods. To get more familiar with my work, See the below code:

```
function FillData(accessUrl, name) {
            var add = accessUrl;
            $.support.cors = true;
            if (add) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: accessUrl,
                    crossDomain: true,
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        Update(name, data);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        LogResponseErrors(status , error, name);
                    }
                });
                setTimeout(function () { FillData(accessUrl, name); }, interval);
                //Consider that the method calls with different parameters one time and it will run automatically with setTimeout
            }
            else {
                freezeFrame(name);
            }
    }
```

Used Tags explains what I used.

Any useful answer will be appreciated

Comment: why don't you put your setTimeout inside $.ajax complete function?

Comment: due to timing problem between ajax and your setTimeout, at some points, there are a lot of events waiting in the queue to be executed and cause performance problem.

Comment: @KhanhTO Do you mean 'Success' function or is there another function named 'Complete'?

Comment: There is another function named "complete" which always executes whether the call succeeded or not. The choise depends on what you need

Comment: I quite believe it's of the problems. The other possible problem you need to check is if the `Update` takes so long to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand in your question. You have delay when you're handling your ajax responses and you need to remove the delay.

Javascript is single-threaded. Therefore, if there is a function that takes long time to complete, it could dominate the thread and cause the UI not responding. To deal with this, you have 2 options:

- Optimize your code so that the function does not take long.
- Use `setTimeout` to break your function into smaller pieces. For example: if your function is executing a loop of 100 items, you could break it to execute 10 times with 10 items each.

**Update:** (based on updated question):

It seems that the loop never stops when you use `setTimeout` like this. Should have something like:

```
counter++;
if (counter <= 12)
setTimeout(function () { FillData(accessUrl, name); }, interval);
```

Due to timing problem between ajax and your `setTimeout`, at some points, there are a lot of events (escalated) waiting in the queue to be executed and cause performance problem. Try putting your `setTimeout` inside your `success` or `complete` function

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer.Considering your answer I will update my question

Comment: Sure , The loop has created to monitor data continuously and will not  stop.

Comment: @A.Mokhtari: ok, but you should not do it like this. Due to timing,  this may cause the events to escalate at some point and cause serious performance problem.

Comment: Ok my friend, So what my options are?

Comment: @A.Mokhtari: put the `setTimeout` inside `success` if you want to reload data only when this call succeeded, or put the `setTimeout` inside `complete` if you need to always reload the data (don't care whether the current ajax succeeded or not). In my opinion, we should put it inside `complete`.

Comment: Unfortunatly, It didn't make any sense